# Implementation of List<T> is losing the ordering on the original query

Tags: asp.net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Using *Entity Framework* I have an `IQueryable` for a database object `Meeting` and `e` is the `DbContext`.

```
IQueryable<Meeting> meetings = e.Meetings
    .Include(m => m.MeetingStage)
    .Include(m => m.MeetingType)
```

This query has had `OrderBy` applied.

I then want to select from this query into a new object `MeetingSearchResult`. However, I'm finding that in certain cases the ordering is being changed, as these tests demonstrate

```
var temp2 = sortedMeetings.Select(m => m.MeetingID);

System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Join(" / ", temp2.ToList().ToArray()));

var temp4 = sortedMeetings.Select(m => new MeetingSearchResult()
{
       MeetingID = m.MeetingID,
       CompanyName = m.CompanyName
});

System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Join(" / ", temp4.ToList().Select(m => m.MeetingID).ToArray()));

var temp8 = sortedMeetings.Select(m => new MeetingSearchResult()
{
      MeetingID = m.MeetingID,
      CompanyName = m.CompanyName,
      MeetingDate = m.MeetingDate,
      MeetingStage = m.MeetingStage.Description
});

System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Join(" / ", temp8.ToList().Select(m => m.MeetingID).ToArray()));
```

The output of the debuggers here is:

```
2493 / 4228 / 7029 / 8254 / 9375 / 10563 / 11716 / 10500
2493 / 4228 / 7029 / 8254 / 9375 / 10563 / 11716 / 10500
2493 / 4228 / 7029 / 8254 / 9375 / 10500 / 10563 / 11716
```

The order of objects in temp8 has changed. Can anyone explain this?

**More info**:

People have asked for more info about what `sortedMeetings` is.

```
var sortedMeetings = meetings.DoMeetingSort(sort, ascending);
```

My extension `DoMeetingSort` follows. I've removed the switch cases that do not apply here:

```
    public static IQueryable<Meeting> DoMeetingSort(this IQueryable<Meeting> query, Constants.MeetingSortColumn column, bool ascending)
    {
        switch (column)
        {
            case Constants.MeetingSortColumn.MeetingType:
                return ascending
                    ? query.OrderBy(m => m.MeetingType.Description).ThenBy(m => m.MeetingDate).ThenBy(m => m.CompanyName)
                    : query.OrderByDescending(m => m.MeetingType.Description).ThenByDescending(m => m.MeetingDate).ThenByDescending(m => m.CompanyName);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try to enumerate the results by calling .ToList()? And why would you try to order anything by an Surrogate key?

Comment: How do you apply OrderBy? What is `temp`? What queries are generated?

Comment: Are there indices applied to the `Meetings` table? Another set fields in select might mean another index used by DB, which might mean another order.

Comment: What is sortedMeetings?

Comment: Added more info about what sortedMeetings is. Meetings table has no indexes other than primary key MeetingID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. The `MeetingSearchResult` object I was returning didn't have a property representing the column being sorted on, so that column wasn't included in the database query. Obvious I guess but had me baffled for ages. Also explains why sorting on other columns worked OK.

+1 to @saamorim for acting as a fresh pair of eyes and pointing me at `context.Database.Log` which I wasn't aware of.

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons why this can happen, but from your sample the most probable is due to the fact that underlying database decides this.
I presume that your `sortedMeetings` is still an `IQueryable` and thus the query is still being constructed. As your're including additional columns and calling `ToList()` different queries are being done to you db engine, and it may decide to use another index, or just another path for you query. If you're using Sql Server, profile your query and see the execution plan, nevertheless use an order by in what you want, it is you only assurance.

But present the `sortedMeetings` with the `OrderBy` for complete analysis.

**EDIT:**

Also, it seems that the origin `IQueryable` is not the same: `temp2` derived drom `sortedMeetings`, `temp4` and `temp8` from `temp`. Also, if you're using EF6, use `context.Database.Log` to dump your queries, otherwise use a database profiler. Post the database queries here and we help you analyse it.

Comment: I suspect you're right @saamorim but doesn't stop this baffling me. I'm using similar logic in many places and this is the only place where the ordering seems to be lost even after thorough testing. Anyway, I've updated my original question with more detail and would appreciate your thoughts.